# IE 11 showing error when i clicking with jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

IE so much confusing me with some errors like this,

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: jquery-2.1.4.min.js, Line:2 Column 2538
```

The weird thing is , on firefox and chrome running well and no error.
And some button with jquery click function is working.

I'm Using IE 11
Before this i'm using jquery-1.1.13.min.js and when i use jquery 2.0 it still running properly on firefox and chrome

I'm really new with cross browser so any info will helping me very much, thanks :)

Comment: Is this page online someplace?

Comment: the page is offline sir , i'm working with my localhost :(

Comment: Please share the code that references jQuery. Did you download it, or are you accessing it from a CDN?

Comment: You should post the code which produced this error..

Comment: @HaryonoSariputra `1.1.13` way old api.

Comment: @Sampson i want to share the code but i don't know where the problem , it just says error syntax and showing the minified jquery.

Comment: @Sampson i'm sorry but its already solved , there is a typo on my one of the js file. lol 

IE works on jquery 1.11.3 without migrate

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Jai Thanks Jai but its already fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record I had this error which only showed itself on IE when doing cross-browser testing of a big Javascript code change.

In my case the problem was a function definition which included what would be a default in any other language:

i.e. Function Foo(param1, param2, param3=false)

.. clearly this was a stupid bit of code .. but it took me a while to track down so this might help someone out there. Doesn't show up in Chrome, FF, or even Edge.

Comment: Thanks for this comment...saved me a ton of time searching through my code to find out why jQuery was erroring out in IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly these errors are not problems of `jQuery` itself. The problem situates in code using `jQuery` or inserted into `jQuery` (callbacks or event functionalities). In my case I used `$.ajax` to load a remote page in a `div` element. In the page I loaded there where `//` comment tags in the `javascript` part. As `IE` is putting this content on one line, more code that as I wanted was commented and this created the error.

So if in our case us are using `$.ajax` maybe this can be an issue. Otherwise best thing to do is debugging the code that generates this error and look for code that is not supported by `IE` (the version you use). Look for functions passed trough to `jQuery`.